# Preimage of $\sigma$-Algebra (Can you check my proof?)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

can you check my proof on the following problem:

"Let $\Omega $ and $\Omega'$ bet sets, $\mathcal{A}'$ a $\sigma$-Algebra in $\Omega'$ and $T:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega'$ a mapping.

Show that $T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}'):=\{T^{-1}(A')|A' \in \mathcal{A}'\}$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra in $\Omega$."

My proof:

I will check the three properties of a $\sigma$-Algebra:

1.) Show that there exists an $A' \in \mathcal{A}'$ such that $\Omega = T^{-1}(A')$, because this proves that $\Omega \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$. For every element $\omega \in \Omega$ we can conclude by definition of $T$ that: $T(\omega) \in \Omega'$. So $\Omega$ is the preimage of $\Omega'$. As $\mathcal{A}'$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra in $\Omega'$, we know that $\Omega' \in \mathcal{A}'$. If you set $A':=\Omega'$, it follows that $\Omega = T^{-1}(\Omega')$ and hence $\Omega \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$.

2.) Show that the complement set $A^c$ of $A$ lies in $T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$. I look for a $A^*\in \mathcal{A}'$ such that $A^c=T^{-1}(A^*)$. As $A \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$ there exists a $A' \in \mathcal{A}'$ with $A = T^{-1}(A')$. I can set $A^*:=A'^c$, and as $\mathcal{A}'$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra $A'^c$ lies in $\mathcal{A}'$. So for all $a \in A^c$ we have $T(a) \notin A'$, as $A$ is the preimage of $A'$ and $A^c$ the complement of $A$. It follwos that $T(A^c) \subseteq A'^c$. So I have found a $A^*$, namely $A'^c$, such that $A^c=T^{-1}(A'^c)$. As a result we have $A^c \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$.

3.) Show that for a sequences of sets $\left(A_n \right)_n \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$ the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i$ lies in $T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$. So I am looking for a $A^* \in \mathcal{A}'$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i=T^{-1}(A^*)$. As $\left(A_n \right)_n \in T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$ there exists for every $A_n$ a $A'_n \in \mathcal{A}'$ with $A_n = T^{-1}(A'_n)$. Further $\mathcal{A}'$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra and so we know that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A'_i \in \mathcal{A}'$. I set $A^*:= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A'_i$. For a arbitrary $a \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i$ we always find a $A'_n$ such that $T(a) \in A'_n$. So it holds that $T(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i) \subseteq A^*$ and hence:
$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i = T^{-1}(A^*)$. Consecuently the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i$ lies in $T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}')$.

As a result $T^{-1}(\mathcal{A}'):=\{T^{-1}(A')|A' \in \mathcal{A}'\}$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra in $\Omega$

Is this proven correctly?

Comment: This looks right if a bit convoluted at times, e.g. for (3) you can simply use the result from elementary set theory that the preimage of a union of sets is equal to the union of preimages. Likewise you can use the fact that the preimage of disjoint sets is disjoint and the above union property to maybe give a cleaner proof of (2).